# How to set Admob Native Ads

Tags: admob, native, ads

I can't show option of native ads on my admob account.
How can I active my native ads. Is anybody know about that.
if anybody know about that so please tell me how can i request to google for activation native ads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [native ads option does not appear in my admob account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809043/native-ads-option-does-not-appear-in-my-admob-account)

Answer (score 0):

google closed the native beta release, you have to wait for new announcement,
Here is the link of blog,
https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/search/label/mobile_ads_sdk

Comment: Thanks... 
but my friend's account still have native ads option.

Comment: reference from :  https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start

**Note: Native Ads Advanced is currently released to a limited set of publishers. If you're interested in participating, reach out to your account manager to discuss the possibility.**